# Tons of [SWF][[DYNAMIC]] tags showing up in my console window

Tags: apache-flex

I looked around online quite a bit and still couldn't find a straight answer to this.

I am working on an application that loads external modules over long periods of time over and over again and in the console window I see the below types of output:

```
[SWF] Users:ME:Sites:MYSITE:MYSWF.swf:[[DYNAMIC]]:6
[SWF] Users:ME:Sites:MYSITE:MYSWF.swf:[[DYNAMIC]]:7
[SWF] Users:ME:Sites:MYSITE:MYSWF.swf:[[DYNAMIC]]:8
[SWF] Users:ME:Sites:MYSITE:MYSWF.swf:[[DYNAMIC]]:9
[Unload SWF] Users:ME:Sites:MYSITE:MYSWF.swf:[[DYNAMIC]]:1
[Unload SWF] Users:ME:Sites:MYSITE:MYSWF.swf:[[DYNAMIC]]:2
[Unload SWF] Users:ME:Sites:MYSITE:MYSWF.swf:[[DYNAMIC]]:3
[Unload SWF] Users:ME:Sites:MYSITE:MYSWF.swf:[[DYNAMIC]]:4
```

Over the course of running the application, the number at the end of this climbs into the thousands. This makes me worry that something is not getting cleaned up or references to something are not being fully disposed of (modules perhaps?). Is this something to be worried about?

Comment: May I ask, why do you keep loading modules over time?!

Comment: Thats a valid point - My understanding of the method I am using is that the modules are only loaded once and then I have a module cache that gets checked to make sure the modules don't get reloaded. However, these messages make me feel like it is not working.